# Rhmobile: How to open rhodes application in console

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

i want to open rhodes application in console mode like we open rails application in console mode.

```
rails console
```

is there any command in rhodes to open a rhodes app in console mode.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Although rhodes uses some concepts of rails framework, it does not have the same tools and behaviors than it and you can not open it in console mode.